# Have I misused templates here?

Tags: c++, templates

I was trying to program generically for a Mesh class.  (I need CPU transformations to deform the meshes, which is why this *isn't* to be done in the GPU, in case you were thinking of asking)

A `Mesh<T>` contains the vertices of a 3d shape, as well as the face tie-up (what vertices join together to make triangles).

Here `T` is the type of vertex, some types of models have PNCT type (position, normal, color, texcoord) and others are just PC (position, color).

```
struct VertexPNCT {
    Vector3 pos, normal ;
    Vector4 color ;
    Vector2 tex ;
} ;

struct VertexPC {
    Vector3 pos ;
    Vector4 color ;
} ;
```

of course, **all** vertices have a position!

But here's my problem.

`Mesh<T>` has to implement a `transform` method.  Of course, every vertex format has a position, and if it's named consistently (`.pos`), then the method works fine:

Since every vertex will definitely have a position, if I always call that member `.pos` in the `Vertex*` struct, then I can add a method `.transform` to the templated class `Mesh<T>` as:

```
void transform( Matrix4& mat )
{
    each vertex
      vertex.pos = mat * vertex.pos ; // transform it
}
```

Now here's the screw up.  *If* the vertex format has a normal in it, then that normal has to be transformed as well (by the "normal matrix").  Now I have an "if statement" in my template?  I have to write a template specialization `.transform` method for each of the vertex types (which basically breaks into 2 categories, those with normals, and those without normals)?

Have I misused templates here?  Missed some "programming boat"?

Here's what I really want to do logically:

```
void transform( Matrix4& mat )
{
    each vertex in vertices
    {
      vertex.pos = mat * vertex.pos ; // transform it
      #ifdef vertex.normal
      vertex.normal = mat * vertex.normal ; // transform normal as well*
      #endif
    }
}
```

<sub>* Assumes no scale in transformation
(then you don't need to use a "normal matrix")</sub>

Comment: What is the type of `Matrix4`? What class holds the `transform` function (or is it a free function)? What is the type of `vertex`? All those questions and probably more, affect the solution. You should show more of the actual problem.

Comment: I think if I understand him correct, transform is in the `Mesh` class.

Comment: Is it necessary that the correct method is picked at runtime. Or can you bind it statically?
You probably can do it statically, you will need to add an extra parameter for the normal matrix right?

Comment: Well I'd _like_ to bind it statically.  The problem is, some vertex formats will just not have a `.normal` member, so the compilation will fail for those formats, if I try to access a `.normal` member inside a `VertexPC`, for example.

Comment: I suggest David's answer then.

Comment: @bobobobo: You are still failing to provide the details of how the `Mesh` type is defined, what the type of `vertex` in your pseudocode is, etc. -1

Comment: Well that gets messier.  A `Mesh<T>` contains a `VertexArray<T>` which in turn provides drawing through OpenGL.  I tried to keep the question focussed on the template business.

Answer (score 3):

If you can write a hierarchy of `Vertex` where the base holds just the position (and `.pos` member), a `VertexWNormal` holds the `.normal` and then the rest inherit from there, you can then just add non-templated overloads and let the compiler handle:

```
void transform( Matrix4& m, VertexBase& v ) {
   // transform only pos
}
void transform( Matrix4& m, VertexWNormal& v ) {
   transform(m,static_cast<VertexBase&>(v));
   // transform normal here
}
void tranform( Matrix4& m ) {
   foreach vertex:
       transform(m,vertex);
}
```

Of course, whether this makes sense with your design or not depends on so many things you are not showing that it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

If you have just two types of vertices, I'd recommend doing what David described above: Just create two functions doing the transformation and have them called using overloading based on the vertex type. This would work with more vertex types as well but every time you add a new vertex type you would need to overload the function again. This may be OK for a simple function as the one described here but it may become annoying if the function is actually more complex.

On partial fix is to create a traits class which tells whether a particular vertex type has a normal member or not. The default could be set such that it is correct in the majority of the cases and a suitable function based on the trait can be selected. You would still provide two versions of the code but for every additional vertex type all what would be needed is to define the traits:

```
template <typename> struct VertexHasNormal { enum { value = false }; };
template <> struct VertexHasNormal<VertexPNCT> { enum { value = true }; };

template <typename V, template T, template S>
void transform(V& vertices, Matrix4& m, T S::*member) {
    for (auto& v: vertices) {
        v.*member = mat * v.*member;
    }
}

template <bool, typename T>
struct Transform {
    template <typename V>
    void call(V& vertices, Matrix4& m) {
        transform(vertices, m, &T::pos);
    }
};
template <typename T>
struct Transform<bool, T> {
    template <typename V>
    void call(V& vertices, Matrix4& m) {
        transform(vertices, m, &T::pos);
        transform(vertices, m, &T::normal);
    }
};

template <typename T>
void Mash<T>::transform(Matrix4& m) {
    Transform<VertexHasNormal::value>::call(this->vertices, m);
}
```

The function template `transform()` is the function doing the actual transformation on a sequence of vertices. I factored it because I think it kind of cute that it can be factored out but it doesn't need to be factored out. Nor does it need to use a pointer to member, `auto`, etc. The `Transform` type is just an auxiliary type used because function templates cannot be partially specialized. It is specialized on whether the the vertex type has the traits for the `normal` member or not. Finally, `Mash<T>::transform()` just dispatches to the appropriate version of the specialied function.

The only thing necessary is to add a new traits specialization when another vertex with a `normal` member gets defined. That may not be desirable. In this case it is possible to determine if a structure has an accessible data member called `normal` using a type trait. However, I don't think I can type this from the top of my head. The basic idea to implement it is to take advantage of the fact that substitution failures are not errors ("
SFINAE") and that things can be set up to create a disambiguity between two potential members if the tested type does have the necessary member. There is a Boost component to do it but if you need to create it yourself it is about 10 to lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make the structs classes and derive them from two base classes, one with normal and one without. Then you can use template specialization to pick between these two base classes (instead of all your vertex classes).